# Apply custom validation to contact form 7

Tags: javascript

I am new to wordpress developement.I wabt to apply my own validation to contatc form 7.Adding same in Header.php file but getting no result.

adding this for mobile number validation in header.php file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#field-mobile").keydown(function(event) { // Allow only backspace and delete 
      if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9) { // let it happen, don't do anything 
      } else {
          // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress 
          if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: please attach your code, and give some details about the validation

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#field-mobile").keydown(function(event) {
    // Allow only backspace and delete
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 ) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});
</script>//adding this for mobile number validation in header.php file

Answer (score 0):

That is so simple, the script does not work since your code is run before your input text is exist on DOM.

You should add $(document).ready() function then put your block of codes in that function.

I guess this is should work now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#field-mobile').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 9) { // let it happen, don't do anything 
    } else {
      console.log('else block')
      if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });

});
```